# Declaring operators using macros

Tags: c++, macros, operators, operator-keyword

```
#define DECLARE_GLOBAL_OPERATOR(OPERATOR) \
X OPERATOR(const X &, const X &);

struct X {};
DECLARE_GLOBAL_OPERATOR(operator+);
```

The code above declares a global addition operator as one would intuitively expect but a simple variation where the macro only accepts the operator symbol doesn't work on Clang 3.5.0 and ideone (tested using C++11).

```
#define DECLARE_GLOBAL_OPERATOR(SYMBOL) \
X operator##SYMBOL(const X &, const X &);

struct X {};
DECLARE_GLOBAL_OPERATOR(+);
```

Here, Clang complains saying `pasting formed 'operator+', an invalid preprocessing token` while ideone outputs `pasting "operator" and "+" does not give a valid preprocessing token`. Is this code ill-formed?

Note that the code below compiles and executes fine, so the problem doesn't seem to be related to passing `+`, `-`, `x`, or `/` arguments to a macro.

```
#define WHATEVER(SYMBOL) \
int value = 2 SYMBOL 4;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be more accurate to say it *declares* a global operator than actually defines it.  The keyword is `operator` and the operator symbol is a separate token.  And you can only paste together identifiers, not an identifier and an operator symbol.

So, you could get the second version to work by dropping the `##`:

```
#define DEFINE_GLOBAL_OPERATOR(SYMBOL) \
            X operator SYMBOL(const X &, const X &);

struct X {};
DEFINE_GLOBAL_OPERATOR(+);
```